# How to tell to JetBrains IDE that this javascript variable changed type to another?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jsdoc

Web API has [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) interface which extends [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) interface.
How to tell JetBrains IDE that this particular Node is Element?

Hope the code below explains everything.

```js
/**
* @param {Node} node 
* @return {string}
*/
function extractor(node) {
   let text;
   if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
       // On the next line IDE shows a warning,
       // that innerHTML property is not defined for Node.
       // How to tell IDE that node variable became and Element here?
       text = node.innerHTML;
   } else {
       text = node.textContent;
   }
   return text;
}
```

I'm using PyCharm Professional, but I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

If you do want, you can use Typescript instead.

```js
text = (node as Element).innerHTML;
```

But in javascript, there is no strict types, you can only try:

```
/**
* @param {Node | Element} node 
* @return {string}
*/
```

Comment: Not possible. But you can disable that warning in JetBrains IDE.

Comment: In my case it is easier tu supress this warning. But thank you for mentioning Typescript. It looks very interesting.